# Reading excel file giving error "can't update read only file"

Tags: c#, .net, excel, oledb

I am trying to read excel file but it giving error

```
Cannot update.  Database or object is read-only.
```

My code is following

```
var fileName = string.Format("{0}\\aa.xlsx.", Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
    var connectionString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; data source={0}; Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;", fileName);

    var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [shell$]", connectionString);
    var ds = new DataSet();

    adapter.Fill(ds, "shell$");

    DataTable data = ds.Tables["shell$"];
```

I never worked with excel file and not sure what this error is about. It says "can't update because ready only" but I am not updating. All I want is to read the file in c#

UPDATED: I don't know what is shell$. I just got it from some other source (the code)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to replace `shell$'` with the name of the sheet in your Excel file that you want to select from.  Let me know if that still gives the read-only problem.